# Can I import contacts from vcf and NOT sync to Google?

Tags: contacts, sync, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s, import

I bought the Nexus S with Android 2.3 and am in the process of migrating my contacts from the Apple Address book. I was able to create and import a vcf file containing all the contacts into Android.

But when I look in the contacts of the phone, I get the message" You don't have any contacts to display". But when I search for a contact, they are found. What's going on?

Can I have my contacts locally on the phone without having them sync with Google first before being accessible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To import a vcf:** Copy the vcf to your phone, then Contacts > Import/Export

**To view hidden contacts**: Contacts > More > Display options, you have the option of displaying "Only contacts with phones" and under "Choose contacts to display" you can choose to view or hide contacts based on their source. Perhaps your contacts are hidden because they are stored in your phone, but you don't check "Phone" under "Choose contacts to display"

**Disclaimer**: I use Froyo (2.2) so the menu name might be different.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Found the option Contacts > More > Display Options. Expanding the google account reveals: 'System Group:My Contacts' and 'All Other Contacts'. Checking both options displays the contacts that are stored on the phone.

Answer (score 3):

I had some problems with built in sync so I looked for a more sophisticated solution. After I tested some apps I choose a Android app called ContactSync (the dev provided me a free test license for the app so +1 for free testing) and the name tells it all. It can sync, import and export contacts on various ways like CardDAV or FTP or just local .vcf files.

Works well here and provides some nice features. The dev has a homepage here -> http://ntbab.dyndns.org/apache2-default/seite/contactsync.html

Answer (score -1):

I use b-card.us to import my contacts. it support iOS as well.
Only register, insert data and scan Barcode. You don't need to install an app and its free.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the app/website or anything of that sort? That would make this answer much more useful to others.